# how to get name of the current command in zsh? (to email yourself shell output in zsh with a good Subject line)

Tags: zsh, tcsh

In tcsh, the most "unscriptable" shell, I often use the following code to email myself output of any command, with the subject line conveniently set exactly to what the command was:

```
~/script.sh | & mail -s "`history 1| cut -f3-`" user@example.org
```

Here's the example session to show that the output I get is exactly as the input command:

```
tcsh% printf "%s\n" "`history 1| cut -f3-`"
printf "%s\n" "`history 1| cut -f3-`"
tcsh%
```

Note that it works perfectly with the long-term history storage, too, and can be modified without having to be written again.

---

I've tried using the following in zsh, but, it's one command behind, so, does not produce the required output, plus it looks pretty ugly with the extra `-d` and `tr` being required:

```
\history -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d\  -f3-
```

I've also tried `!#` in zsh, but it results in broken history (stuff gets duplicated), and doesn't even work even work properly by itself, either:

```
zsh% printf "%s\n" "!#"
dquote>
```

Is there any way in zsh to get the whole command line that's being executed such that it could be used as the subject line for the email?

Comment: It seems that the question and answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/456508 could help. In short, it could be `"$history[$(print -P %h)]"` or `"$history[${(%):-%h}]"`  to get the current command line.

Comment: @hchbaw thanks, that works!  Also, `${history[$((${#history[@]} - 1))]}` seems to work, too, although unlike bash, `-1` as an index doesn't work, and also `$(())` is required in zsh, unlike bash.  Also, the supposedly old bash way of accessing the last element with `${history[@]:(-1)}` doesn't work, either.  It might take a while to be able to write this abracadabra from scratch; but copy-paste and history works 100% as required with `$history[${(%):-%h}]`.